# Make special navbar in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm learning HTML, CSS and Bootstrap and I have some questions how I can make a navbar like this. Thanks!
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVoi4.png

Comment: Sorry, but this requires quite a lot of custom CSS. You can use Firebug/Chrome DevTools to play around with Bootstrap default navbar. Stuck on some code? Post it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Add bootstrap  https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css


Use this demo 

<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
```